# Web worker importScripts fails to place script variables in global scope

Tags: namespaces, web-worker

TL;DR I have a worker which imports two objects via importScripts. They do not appear in "self". Moz docs say:

```
        importScripts() method of the WorkerGlobalScope interface 
        synchronously imports one or more scripts into the worker's scope.
```

So where are they?!

Details:
Three files: index.html, worker.js, foo.js

index.html contains:

```
const worker = new Worker('./worker.js')
worker.postMessage({ file: './foo.js', var: 'foo' })
```

worker.js contains:

```
onmessage = e => {
    params = e.data
    console.log('worker: params', params)
    console.log('worker: this === self', this === self)
    importScripts(params.file)
    console.log(self[params.var], eval(params.var), foo)
}
```

foo.js contains:

```
const foo = { one: 1, two: 2 }
const bar = { three: 3, four: 4 }
```

I.e. the html passes the path and variable name to the worker which imports the path and, using the name of the variable, attempts to find it in "self". Fails.

Yet using either "eval" or the variable itself, not its name, works as expected.

Here are the console messages:

```
worker: params {file: "./foo.js", var: "foo"}
worker: this === self true
undefined {one: 1, two: 2} {one: 1, two: 2}
```

So where does the worker place the variables imported from foo.js?!

NB: this may seem like an odd thing to do, why not just use the variable? Deep reasons exist having to do with a highly (re)factored repo.

Comment: Just doing some quick testing in the console it looks like if you use `var` the variable will be added on the window itself whereas using `const` or `let` does not and just places the variables at the top scope. Maybe the same thing applies here?

Comment: You got it, "var" fixed the problem. Wow, whoda thought. If you turn this into an "answer" I can give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `const` and `let` to declare variables does not add them to the global scope object, such as the workers `self` or `window` (see [MDN description for const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description)). Using `var` does, however:

```
const x = 1;
let y = 2;
var z = 3;

console.log(window.x, window.y, window.z);
// undefined undefined 3
```

Changing your variable declarations for `foo` and `bar` to use `var` should fix the problem.